# editing file through vi editor in shell script show error

Tags: linux, bash, vim, vi

script in which I open a file in vi editor , after that user will write any thing in it then save or quite by `:wq!`

When I try this then it give an error message as below

```
e138 can't write viminfo file $home/.viminfo!
```

and ask for,

```
Press Enter or command to continue
```

Now when I press enter then file save. But why that error message shows.
If I open same file direct with vi editor or vim editor and do changes then it does not give any error.

also if I install vim editor then it works fine and no error shows

Please tell me what may be the issue.

Comment: your question is incomplete.  There is no actual script and you haven't explained how exactly you run the script

Comment: The command is `:wq` not `:wq!`, which is equal to `:x` (`:wq`). Not to be confused with "quit with discarding any changes" `:q!`.

Comment: can you show how did you call vim in your script?

Comment: In linux, it's $HOME. Can't say much without looking at the script but looks like permision issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my best guess is that `$home` is not defined properly. try running: `!echo $home` on both editors. If it's not defined during the script run, define it before running vim.

Comment: thanks for response, yes I try echo $HOME in script and it does not print any thing, could you please tell me how to define home in the script

Comment: @agarwal_achhnera I would start by looking into bash environment variables (I see from your question tags you're using bash). Try to be more focused on the problem and giving some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with mostly the same error, but this answer did not work for me. I had to create more space within my $HOME directory by deleting a few files, and then vim worked normally again.